# Using Grafana, how can I create a time series chart which links to specific time ranges?

Tags: hyperlink, grafana

I have a dashboard with three time series charts in Grafana 10 showing temperatures.
The first chart displays the last 24h of collected temperatures, the second one aggregates the last 30 days in blocks of 24h (min/max/avg per day), the third one aggregates the last year on a monthly basis (i.e. 12 sets of min/max/avg).

Chart 2 and 3 are bar charts and have a fixed relative time range, i.e. do not depend on the dashboard's "from" and "to" values.

I would like to create Chart 2 so that if I click on any of the last 30 days, the data of **this day** will be displayed in Chart 1, i.e. the dashboard's "from" and "to" values will be adjusted accordingly.

If possible, I would also like to create Chart 3 so that if I click on any month, the data of **that month** will be displayed in Chart 2.

Is this possible using Grafana, possibly with a plugin, and if so, how?

I know that I can click & drag to zoom into a single graph, but this is not really what I intend to do. Dragging does not work well with mobile devices, selecting precise starts and ends of days and months is really hard, and it also does not work with otherwise fixed time ranges.

Comment: Try setting `from` parameter using data link option and field like `${__field.time}`, and  `&to=now%2Fd`